# ClassNotFound exception when extracting a class from a jar

Tags: java, classloader

I've been unsuccessfully trying to get a class from a .jar file. The .jar is located at C:\CTF.jar and contains a .class file CaptureTheFlagRules in a folder named CTF. The following code does not work:

```
try {
    File jarFile = new File("C:\\CTF.jar");
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] 
        { jarFile.toURI().toURL() }, getClass.getClassLoader());
    Class<?> unknownClass = Class.forName("CaptureTheFlagRules", 
        true, urlClassLoader); 
    ....
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

The code throughs a ClassNotFoundException at the forName() call. What do I need to do to get my class?

Comment: Why don't you just add it to your classpath so you can use it normally?

Comment: Is the CaptureTheFlagRules class inside a namespace?  If so you will need to add the namespace to the Class.forName() call.  ex: Class.forName("com.galecki.CaptureTheFlagRules")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Class<?> unknownClass = Class.forName("CTF.CaptureTheFlagRules", 
    true, urlClassLoader);
```

If it's in the CTF folder, it's probably in the CTF package.